# SparklyR Streaming and JDBC

Tags: r, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, sparklyr

Could you provide an example of using the SparklyR [`stream_read_jdbc()`](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/stream_read_jdbc/):

> ```
> stream_read_jdbc(sc, path, name = NULL, columns = NULL,
>     options = list(), ...)
> ```

and [`stream_write_jdbc()`](https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/stream_write_jdbc/),

> ```
> stream_write_jdbc(x, mode = c("append", "complete", "update"),
>   trigger = stream_trigger_interval(),
>   checkpoint = file.path("checkpoints", random_string("")),
>   options = list(), ...)
> ```

preferably connecting to Oracle? If the sample uses any other database that is OK.  Why is there a path parameter to a file while reading from JDBC?  Is it not the point to source from a database instead of from the filesystem?

Comment: I haven't been able to find an example of how to use these functions, so I haven't tried anything yet.  I want to be able to stream from a database via JDBC so that when a JDBC table gets new records inserted, the Spark streaming process will automatically detect the added data and write it to a sink.  I wonder if I haven't been able to find an example because this is "dead code" as mentioned below.  Why would the folks at SparklyR provide these empty functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `spakrlyr` indeed provide following functions:

- `stream_read_jdbc`
- `stream_write_jdbc`

this is effectively a piece of dead code, as Spark Structured Streaming doesn't support streaming reads and writes with JDBC source.